# create_protected_copy Crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

There is one crash logged in firebase `create_protected_copy`. This is happening in iOS 16 + versions. But I am not able to understand this crash.

Here is the screenshot of full log:-
[image: crash Log]

Please help me out to understand how I can resolve this. Any sugessions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the stack trace of the relevant crash log

Comment: Given the limited information in this question, I don't think it's suitable for this site. As such, I'll only comment. Your general course of action should be: check the crash logs, update firebase SDK, check for memory issues, look at thread safety in your firebase calls, use exception breakpoints, and if none of that works, reach out to firebase support.